# Unreadable data through FT232RL

Tags: c++, serial-port, ftdi

I'm using a USB to UART adapter (with FT232RL) for serial communication between to computer devices (PC<->Jetson Nano, Jetson Nano<->Jetson Nano).

When I send data through the FTDI adapter, the data becomes unreadable. Sending (USB): "asdqwe"
Receiving (UART): "OFST"

The other way is like:
Sending (UART): "asdqwe"
Receiving (USB): "OFST"

To check if there is anything wrong with my code, I send UART to UART, which is working fine.

Anyone having experience with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some special characters between S and T, and the backend of T in the received data that do not appear here.

Comment: First check configuration of UART matches PC's, i.e parity, byte size, speed

Answer (score 0):

**first you need to stop serial console by these commands**

```
$ systemctl stop nvgetty
$ systemctl disable nvgetty
$ udevadm trigger
# You may want to reboot instead
```

then

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyTHS1
```

`for pin 8/10 uart permission access`

**use gkterminal to see it working**